# Xcode 5 accounts view details is grayed out

Tags: xcode5, ios-provisioning

I am an individual developer and when I try to access my provisioning profiles I cannot access the **Xcoe**-->**Prefences**-->**Accounts**-->**View Details** button since it is grayed out.

The table in this screen shows **"No Teams"**.

With previous Xcode versions I had no problem accessing the profiles (via organizer).

I can view the profiles in the **iOS Dev Center** portal with no problems.

So my question is why can't I access the profiles in xcode ? (I have two old profiles that I deleted from the portal and I want to refresh Xcode since I have two warnings about these profiles)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the apple ID and then adding it again. Not sure why but this enables the "View Details" button again.